# Find duplicate values on selected rows in table jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table in my HTML,

```
<table>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>2</td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>x</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </table>
```

And i wanted to find duplicate contents in the first and the second `<td>` elements contents.

This is what i got so far:

```
$(function() {
        $("table tr").each(function() {

        });
    });
```

I m stuck on selecting the first and the second element and comparing them. Do i just add a class or use jquery selector?

Comment: What do you want to do when you find dupes? And I'm assuming that you mean duplicate values in the same column between rows.

Comment: yes exactly and remove the duplicates

Comment: So in your example, the last row, first column should be cleared, and every second column except the first (containing a 2) should be cleared?

Comment: So basically in my example  the first and the last row would be cleared -they both have the same <td> element  in the first and the second column.(These are the only columns i wanted to compare for same values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just store the combination of the first two values as properties in an object

```
$(function() {
   var el = {};
   $("table tr").each(function() {
        // get row
        var row = $(this);
        // get first and second td
        var first = row.find('td:first-child').val();
        var second = row.find('td:nth-child(2)').val();
        // if exists, remove the tr
        if(el[first + second]) {
            $(this).remove())
        }
        else {
            // if it does not exist, add it with some random val
            el[first + second] = 1;
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you find the duplicates in a column, if I understood.

You can use instead of `.addClass`, `.remove()` if you want to remove it.

http://jsbin.com/wenuwewide/edit?js,console,output

```
  $('tr').each(function() {

      $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {

        if(values[i].indexOf($(this).text()) > -1) {
          $(this).addClass('duplicate');
        }

        values[i].push($(this).text());          
      });

    });
```